# Como ficar com apenas com uma parte da string?

Tags: php, string

Tenho várias string's (idPergunta-18, idResposta-18, idPergunta-17, idResposta-17)

Necessitava escrever apenas (idPergunta, idResposta, idPergunta, idResposta)

Como faço em PHP?

O objetivo é o seguinte:

Neste momento tenho o seguinte array que vem de um $_POST

```
array(28) { ["privacidade-16"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-16"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-16"]=> string(2) "16" ["resposta-16"]=> string(5) "vitor" ["privacidade-17"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-17"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-17"]=> string(2) "17" ["resposta-17"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09" ["privacidade-18"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-18"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-18"]=> string(2) "18" ["idRespostaPre-18"]=> string(2) "19" ["privacidade-19"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-19"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-19"]=> string(2) "19" ["resposta-19"]=> string(3) "Rua" ["privacidade-20"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-20"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-20"]=> string(2) "20" ["idRespostaPre-20"]=> string(2) "22" ["privacidade-21"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-21"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-21"]=> string(2) "21" ["resposta-21"]=> string(4) "4465" ["privacidade-30"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-30"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta-30"]=> string(2) "30" ["idRespostaPre-30"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "186" [1]=> string(3) "187" [2]=> string(3) "188" [3]=> string(3) "189" } }
```

O que preciso é separar este array num array com vários arrays lá dentro e teria de separar da seguinte maneira

um array com:
array[0] = ["privacidade"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta"]=> string(2) "16" ["resposta"]=> string(5) "vitor"

array[1] = ["privacidade-17"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada-17"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta"]=> string(2) "17" ["resposta"]=> string(10) "2015-10-09"

array[2] = ["privacidade"]=> string(1) "1" ["verificada"]=> string(1) "1" ["idPergunta"]=> string(2) "18" ["idRespostaPre"]=> string(2) "19"

por aí em diante, isto porque os campos que vêm do POST são dinâmicos ou seja hoje são 10 mas amanha podem ser 20

Comment: todas assim, separados por um traço?

Comment: Essa edição me parece outra pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazer um replace com uma expressão regular, que combine `-[0-9]`, use a função `preg_replace()` para isso.

Caso a string seja apenas `idPergunta-18`, utilize  [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) e informe o terceiro argumento(`$before_needle`) como `true`, essa função encontra a primeira ocorrência do delimitador e divide ela, por padrão o retorno é a parte a direita do delimitador, caso queira mudar isso informe o terceiro argumento.

```
<?php 
//opção 1
$str = '(idPergunta-18, idResposta-18, idPergunta-17, idResposta-17)';
echo  preg_replace('/\-[0-9]+/', '', $str);
//opção 2
echo strstr('idPergunta-18', '-', true);
```

Saída:

```
(idPergunta, idResposta, idPergunta, idResposta)
idPergunta
```

Comment: Acho que a ideia era tratar string a string.

Comment: @JorgeB. não entendi

Comment: tipo `idPergunta-18` => `idPergunta`

Comment: @JorgeB. a segunda opção parece adequada?

Comment: Sim, a mim parece.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode resolver também pegando a posição do delimitador '-' com `strripos()` e  cortar apenas o que você precisa com `substr()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$palavra = 'idPergunta-18';
$posicaoDeCorte = strripos($palavra, '-');
echo substr($palavra, 0,$posicaoDeCorte);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/l4YeWM)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual intuito você tem com isso, mas já deixando de um modo que abra varias possibilidade de trabalhar.

#### Codigo

```
preg_match_all("~(id\w+)-(\d+)~", $str, $matches);

$matches[1]; // ARRAY DE PERGUNTA / RESPOSTA
$matches[2]; // ARRAY DE ID
```

#### Exibindo

```
echo implode(' , ', $matches[2]); // idPergunta, idResposta, idPergunta, idResposta
```

#### Relacionando

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $value){
    $name = $value;
    $id = $matches[2][$k];
}
```